# UIFont fontWithName return nil

Tags: objective-c, uifont

This code return Me nil in font.

I add the open sans ttf file to project folder.

What am I missing?

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:fontSize];
    if (font)
    {
        [str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:font size:fontSize] range:NSMakeRange(location, length)];
        label.attributedText = str;
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all are your .ttf files registered in your **.plist** file ? 
Second are your fonts added to "**Copy Bundle Resources**" ? **(Under Target->Build Phases)**

Next try this code to list all usable fonts and their names. This way you can make sure you use the right identifier for your font.

```
for (NSString* fontFamily in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontFamily];
    NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
}
```

**Edit**

Since this answer is a bit old I updated it with the corresponding answer for **Swift 3.0**:

```
_ = UIFont.familyNames.map {
    let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: $0)
    print("Font Family: \($0), Font Names: \(fontNames)\n")
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone !  I also used this link.

Comment: Thanks, you said an issue which no body pay attention to it in answer question! --> Second are your fonts added to **"Copy Bundle Resources" ? (Under Target->Build Phases)**